# Convert comma delimited string to list

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell code:

```
$Credentials = 'Credentials: myacct1,myacct2'

$runtimes = $Credentials -match "Credentials: (?<content>.*)"
$runtimeList = $matches['content']
Foreach ($runtime in $runtimeList)
{
    Write-Host $runtime
}
```

That simply returns `myacct1,myacct2` where I want it to iterate through the list

```
myacct1
myacct2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just need to split the matched string by `,` using `String.Split()`.

```
$Credentials = 'Credentials: myacct1,myacct2'

$runtimes = $Credentials -match "Credentials: (?<content>.*)"
$runtimeList = $matches['content'].Split(",")
Foreach ($runtime in $runtimeList)
{
    Write-Host $runtime
}

# Output:
# myacct1
# myacct2
```

Comment: You got it!  I actually found at the same time but this is correct as well.  I did the following `$runtimeList = $matches['content'] -split ','`

Comment: If not containing spaces (or other special characters) you can treat the named capture group like a property: `$runtimeList = $matches.content.Split(",")` (+1)

Answer (score 2):

To offer a more PowerShell-idiomatic solution:

```
PS> 'Credentials: myacct1,myacct2' -replace '^Credentials: ' -split ','
myacct1
myacct2
```

- `-replace '^Credentials: '` strips prefix `Credentials:`  from the string (replaces it with the (implied) empty string).
- `-split ','` splits the remaining string into an array of tokens by `,`

Comment: or `-split ' ')[1] -split ','`